# Passing value in HTML URL link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$.post("/diabetes/ropimages/getcount.php",{pid:$("#patient_id").val()} ,function(data1){
  //alert(data1);
  var count = data1;
  var pid = $("#patient_id").val();
  var rid;

  for( var i = 1 ; i <= count ; i++) {
    var link ='<img src="/diabetes/ropimages/thumbpicdisplay.php?pid=+pid+&rid=1" />';
    $("#content1").empty().html(link);
  }
});
```

I am trying to pass pid value in url ..but its taking directly as +pid+ as value ..how do i give it the value of pid.

And how do i print 3 images in a div? like the one in code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to terminate the string after `?pid=` and then use the [concatenation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/String_Operators) (`+`) to "insert" the `pid` variable in the appropriate location:

```
'<img src="/diabetes/ropimages/thumbpicdisplay.php?pid=' + pid + '&rid=1" />'
```

As for attaching the 3 images to the div, you might have more luck doing the following:

```
var link = '';

for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
   link += '<img src="...thumbpicdisplay.php?pid=' + pid + '&rid=1" />';
}

$("#content1").empty().html(link);
```

Comment: hey i wrote code like this... for 1st loop it works then it stops working can u just tell me where i  am going wrong

Comment: $.getJSON("/diabetes/ropimages/getcount.php",{pid:$("#patient_id").val()} ,function(data1){
 
var i;
var count = data1.count;
 
var start = data1.start;
 
var pid = $("#patient_id").val();
 
 
for(i = start ; i <= count ; i++)
{
var link ='<a href="/diabetes/ropimages/origpicdisplay.php?pid='+pid+'&rid='+i+'"><img src="/diabetes/ropimages/thumbpicdisplay.php?pid='+pid+'&rid='+i+'"/><a>';
alert(link);
if(i > start)
{
$("#content1").append(link);
}
else{
$("#content1").empty().html(link);
}
 
}
},"Json");

Comment: @pradeep: What value of `count` are you getting?

Comment: i am getting start value as 6 and count as 3 .when i try to add those 2 like count = count+start; and print it ..it gives like 36 instead of 9 . i think its taken it as string ..how to solve this prob?

Comment: you can use `parseInt(count) + parseInt(start)` to avoid that problem.